# What should I install if server name is empty when trying to connect to server in MSSQL 2014 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I just installed the SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, after this I was trying to connect to server but the rectangle with "server name" was empty and the "browse for more" too:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htxby.jpg)

Months ago, I took a class related to this but the rectangle was always with some name and I did the queries without knowing what was that. I thought that in my laptop would be the same and it would detect my local server but that didn't happen.

I read something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498005/sql-server-managemet-studio-not-finding-local-server and like the answer suggests there wasn't any entry in SQL Server Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager that looks like `SQL server(instance name)` [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1RCn.jpg)

He says that what I installed was

> only the Management Studio - the GUI - but that does not contain the
>   actual SQL Server core engine - you need to get and install that,
>   too!!

Therefore, what should I install? I can't add a comment there because I don't have enough reputation. Any answer is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone need it, too: Install MSSQL Express 2014 and run its set up(inside), then select "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server" and keep going as usual...

(I'm so sorry about my wrong formulated question, but thank you so much to the people who helped me, I REALLY appreciate it)